# PHP Soap con cabeceras

Tags: php, soap

Estoy intentando consumir **SOAP** con **php** de un webservice donde necesito añadir unas cabeceras a la llamada pero estoy teniendo problemas.

Un ejemplo de las cabeceras que necesito añadir son las siguientes. Están probadas con **SOAPUI** y funcionan correctamente:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:orac="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP55G001/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>  
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
         </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>  
   <soapenv:Body>
      <orac:getItemsInfo>            
         <codeic>CLIENT</codeic>            
         <products>    
            <itemCode>843841</itemCode>    
         </products>
      </orac:getItemsInfo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

El caso es que con la función `__getFunctions()` el webservice me muestra las funciones disponibles pero en el momento de hacer la llamada me da error.
He probado varias formas de hacer la llamada desde **php** pero en todas obtengo error.

> Could not connect to host

Os muestro ejemplos de lo que he intentado, que algo estaré haciendo mal y se me escapa:

```
public static function getPartNumber($partNumber)
{
    
    $wsdl = "URL DEL WEBSERCISE";    

    $options = array( 'style'=>SOAP_RPC, 'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED, 'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'connection_timeout'=>15, 'trace'=>true, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'exceptions'=>true,      
    );
    
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);  
    
    $headers = new \SoapVar('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:orac="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP55G001/">
        <soapenv:Header>
            <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                  <wsse:UsernameToken>
                      <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>  
                          <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
                  </wsse:UsernameToken>
              </wsse:Security>
        </soapenv:Header>  
        <soapenv:Body>
            <orac:getItemsInfo>          
              <codeic>CODIGO CLIENTE</codeic>          
              <products>  
                  <itemCode>843841</itemCode>
              </products>       
            </orac:getItemsInfo>
        </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>', XSD_ANYXML);        

    $client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);    

    return $client->getItemsInfo($partNumber);     
  }
}
```

Otro ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```
public static function getPartNumber($partNumber)
{
    
    $wsdl = "URL DEL WEBSERVICE";
    
    $codClient = "CODIGO CLIENTE";

    $options = array('style'=>SOAP_RPC, 'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED, 'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'connection_timeout'=>15, 'trace'=>true, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'exceptions'=>true);
    
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);         

    $headers = array(
      'UsernameToken' => array('Username' => 'USERNAME', 'Password' => 'PASSWORD')
    );

    $header = new SOAPHeader($wsdl, 'RequestorCredentials', $headers); 

    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);    

    return $client->getItemsInfo($codClient, $partNumber); 
}
```

Agradecería vuestra ayuda sobre como puedo hacer esto.
Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Ese error no es de formato sino de una capa más abajo. Prueba si puedes conectarte a esa IP en el puerto correspondiente (`telnet ip puerto` por ejemplo).

Comment: @Alfabravo     Gracias por la respuesta. Efectivamente probando a conectarme con telnet y el puerto no llega a conectar. Si hago ping a la IP. Lo que me despista es que con  __getFunctions() Si establece comunicación y devuelve las funciones disponibles.